# How to monitor specific spiders with Spidermon?

Tags: python, scrapy, spidermon

I'm following Spidermon's documentation on monitoring Spiders, in their examples, the monitors that they create seem to run across all of their Spiders, I can't figure out how to run a monitor on a single Spider.

I've tried passing my Spider into test_min_items, but I don't know where to set this.

```py
from spidermon import Monitor, MonitorSuite, monitors

@monitors.name('Item count')
class ItemCountMonitor(Monitor):

    @monitors.name('Minimum number of items')
    def test_min_items(self):
        item_extracted = getattr(
            self.data.stats, 'item_scraped_count', 0)
        minimum_threshold = 10

        msg = 'Extracted less than {} items'.format(
            minimum_threshold)
        self.assertTrue(
            item_extracted > minimum_threshold, msg=msg
        )


class SpiderCloseMonitorSuite(MonitorSuite):

    monitors = [
        ItemCountMonitor
    ]
```

Answer (score 6):

There different ways to achieve this.

1. Every monitor test method has a data.spider property (https://spidermon.readthedocs.io/en/latest/monitors.html#id1) that contains the instance of the spider you are running. You could include an if-statement in your monitor verifying its name and doing what you want according to your monitor:

```
@monitors.name('Item count')
class ItemCountMonitor(Monitor):

    @monitors.name('Minimum number of items')
    def test_min_items(self):
        if self.data.spider.name == "somespider":
            ...  # Do something
        else:
            ...  # Do other thing
```

2. You can have different monitors enabled for different spiders using custom-settings (https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/settings.html#settings-per-spider).

```
# spider1.py
class MySpider1(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'myspider1'

    custom_settings = { 
        'SPIDERMON_SPIDER_CLOSE_MONITORS': (
            'myproject.Spider1MonitorSuite',
        )   
    }   

# spider2.py
class MySpider2(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'myspider2'

    custom_settings = { 
        'SPIDERMON_SPIDER_CLOSE_MONITORS': (
            'myproject.Spider2MonitorSuite',
        )   
    }
```

And for each MonitorSuite you include only the monitors that makes sense for wach spider.

3. Specifically to a monitor that verifies a minimum number of items, we have a built-in monitor (https://spidermon.readthedocs.io/en/latest/monitors.html#spidermon.contrib.scrapy.monitors.ItemCountMonitor) that you can use. So you can set different `SPIDERMON_MIN_ITEMS` setting for each spider using the `custom_setting` mentioned previously.